# Css3 Keyframe in IE (background-image:)

Tags: css, keyframe

Hello i am new to working with css keyframes and having some problems. Any help would make my day. Is the code below supported in IE ?  Works very nice in chrome.

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
 0%{

   background-image: url(../images/hero/p1.gif);

 }
 33%{
   background-image: url(../images/hero/p2.gif);

 }
 66%{
   background-image: url(../images/hero/p3.gif);

 }
 100%{
   background-image: url(../images/hero/p4.png);

 }
}
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Keyframe animations not supported before IE10, I'm pretty sure. http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation

Comment: Why not try? You can use w3schools to check the availability of certain CSS or JS features

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support transitions and animations on the `background-image` property.